# Can I use use llap feature with hive 1.2.1000 in hdp 2.6?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a HDP 2.6 cluster with hive 1.2.1000...can I use the new LLAP feature with this version of hive in HDP cluster?

Answer (score 0):

LLAP is available with Hive**2**, which is already a part of HDP 2.5+ and can be enabled in Ambari's Hive settings if it isn't already.

You will need to install the LLAP Interactive query service on a host